# XML Parser returning #text instead of the node name, i dont know where they are coming from

Tags: java, xml

Below is a snippet of code I am working on to parse some XML, but I cant work out how to properly move down the DOM tree.

Now when I run my code, I return the top node (root node?) which is DistanceResponseMatrix, it has 9 child nodes.

I am trying to loop through the child nodes, for all `rowResponseList.item(i).getNodeName()` (9 nodes) its returning #text .I was expecting a node list containing row, element and so on,which would align with the XML.

obviously I am going wrong somewhere, any help is greatly appreciated.

Xml :

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>97 London Rd, Manchester M1 2PG, UK</origin_address>
<destination_address>1 Aytoun St, Manchester M1 3DB, UK</destination_address>
 <row>
 <element>
  <status>OK</status>
   <duration>
    <value>230</value>
    <text>4 mins</text>
   </duration>
   <distance>
    <value>888</value>
    <text>0.9 km</text>
    </distance>
   <duration_in_traffic>
    <value>215</value>
    <text>4 mins</text>
   </duration_in_traffic>
  </element>
 </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();      
    //URL need to be broken out into variables
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=53.474073,-2.230146&destinations=53.480037,-2.235950&mode=driving&language=en-FR&departure_time=now&key=");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
        NodeList dmrResponseList = doc.getElementsByTagName("DistanceMatrixResponse");
        System.out.println(dmrResponseList.getLength());

        for(int i = 0 ;i<dmrResponseList.getLength();i++) {
            Node p1 = dmrResponseList.item(i);
        String dmrstr = p1.getNodeName();
        System.out.println(dmrstr); // print out the name

        //if the node is an element node (should be) 
            if(p1.getNodeType() ==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NodeList  rowResponseList  = p1.getChildNodes(); // dont forget to cast when you get to an elemt
                System.out.println(rowResponseList.getLength());

                String rowstr = rowResponseList.item(i).getNodeName();
                System.out.println(rowstr); // print out the name


                //String areaStr = area.getAttribute("qtd");
                for(int j = 0 ;j<p1.getChildNodes().getLength();j++ ) {
                    Node k = rowResponseList.item(j);
                    if(k.getNodeType()== Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        //Element name = (Element) k;
                        //String nameStr = name.getAttribute("name");
                        //System.out.println(areaStr + nameStr);
                        System.out.println(rowResponseList.item(j).getNodeName());
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }       
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Looking at your XML, the `<DistanceMatrixResponse>` has 4 child nodes and not 9; `<status>`,`<origin_address>`,`<destination_address>` and `<row>`. Node `<row>` has `<element>` as a child and so on. Please explain what is the desired output you are expecting from the `Java` code.

Comment: thats what i thought, i therefore cant work out why System.out.println(dmrResponseList.getLength()) is returning 9. I dont neccessarily want to return anything just yet, this is purely a learning excercise to learn how to work through the nodes. i realise that's not very helpful. I'm just looking for an explanation why text is being returned and not <status>,<origin_address>,<destination_address> and row i might be able to work out the rest.

Comment: use Node.ELEMENT_NODE instead of Node.TEXT_NODE

Comment: and use item(j).getTextContent() to get the value